# Reposition html elements when window window is resized

Tags: css, mobile, dynamic, position

I have 3 elements in a row. When the window is resized to be narrower, I want the center element to move to the top and the right element to move to the bottom. The left element should then be in the middle. Ideally they should all move at the same time, so if the right most element moves down, the center element should move up too.

Thanks for your help!

The pictures show the desired result.

[image: Wide]
[image: Narrow]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="left">This should go in between</span>
    <span class="center">This should go ABOVE</span>
    <span class="right">This should go BELOW</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container span {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: calc(100% /3);
  width: 33.33%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .right {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .center {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40mqjf3g/27/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a couple solutions to this. The @media css rule handles when the screen width shrank below a certain width. Here's an example: 
[Solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ExMSA/)

The solution I ended up going with was using flexbox and the "order" property to set the order of the elements. Then the @media rule changes the order # when the screen was thin enough.

Here's solution 1 (I didn't write this):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-w">        
        <div class="block center">Center</div>  
        <div class="block left">Left</div>
        <div class="block right">Right</div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- .container -->

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden; /* should be clearfix instead */
}

.container .inner-w {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* should be clearfix instead */
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 10em; /* just for show */
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {  

    .center {
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        left: 25%;
    }

    .left {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .right {
        float: right;
        width: 25%;    
    }
} /* end break-point */















/* just for show */
.container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container .inner-w {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}

.block {
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 10em; /* just for show */
    padding: 1em;
}
```